# Access Azure DevOps secret inside a process started by powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell, azure-devops

**ADO secret variable:** `MY_SECRET_VAR=blablabla`

**ADO powershell script as build task:**

```
# secrets aren't automatically env variables - so try to explicitly set it
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MY_SECRET_VAR]$(MY_SECRET_VAR)"

# run a node.js script that needs to use the secret
npm run <my-node-script>
```

**Node.js script**:

```
process.env.MY_SECRET_VAR   //undefined
```

How do I access secrets as environment variables from node.js?

Comment: You pass it as a parameter. Secret variables intentionally do not get populated as environment variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secrets in Azure DevOps builds (dotnet core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653936/secrets-in-azure-devops-builds-dotnet-core)

Comment: @DanielMann So I should set my ps build task arguments to: `-MY_SECRET_VAR $(MY_SECRET_VAR)` which gives my ps script the variable. But then I still want my node.js script to access it as an environement variable, and I can't do that? So I'd be forced to pass the variable from ps to the node script as an argument as well?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @DanielMann should secrets be passed to PS tasks via arguments? I thought using the `Environment Variables` section under `Control Options` was the [designed method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer%2Cbatch#secret-variables) for passing secret values from a pipeline to a PS script.